# Can't type in React input text field in Todo app

Tags: reactjs, forms

I am making a todo app in React.js but stuck in this part. I can not type in input field. Please help me.

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
```

export default class AddItem extends Component {
    state = 
        {
            title: "",
            done: false
        }

```
changeTitle = (e) =>{
    e.preventDefault();
    this.setState = ({
        title: e.target.value
    });
}

addNewItem = (item) => {
    item.preventDefault();
    let newTask = {
        title: this.state.title,
        done: false
    };
    this.props.additem(newTask);
    this.setState = ({
        title: ""
    });
} 

render() {
    return (
        <div>
            <form>
                <input 
                    type="text"
                    placeholder="add task name." 
                    value={this.state.title} 
                    onChange= {this.changeTitle}
                />
                <button type = "button" onClick= {this.addNewItem} >submit</button>
            </form>
        </div>
    )
}
```

}

Comment: could you share a link to codesandbox?

Comment: this.setState is a function that you have to call with the changes

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`this.setState` is a function that is called with an object containing changes in state. The code you are using here is an assignment *not* a function call:

```
 this.setState = ({
        title: e.target.value // Wrong
    });
```

Instead, call the `setState` function with the changes/updates in state. the changes are shallow merged and only title is updated here.

```
this.setState({title:e.target.value});
```

You will have a similar problem inside `addNewItem`.